# CheckBox spacing next to TextView and Button

Tags: android

my checkbox seems to be screwing with my layout quite a bit.

This is what I want:

```
Button  | CheckBox  | TextView
```

but the CheckBox is pushing my textview way right

```
Button  | CheckBox  |                  TextView
```

my xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/signin_button"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:padding="5dp"
               android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
               android:background="@layout/bordersignin"
               android:textColor="#ffffff"
               android:text="@string/signin" />

           <CheckBox
               android:id="@+id/staysignedin"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="@string/staysignedin" />

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="left|center"
               android:text="Stay signed in" />
       </LinearLayout>
```

Upadated code and it still pushes the text to the right. Wieghts have no effect on the horizontal movement of them.

```
           <Button
               android:id="@+id/signin_button"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
               android:background="@layout/bordersignin"
               android:padding="5dp"
               android:text="@string/signin"
               android:textColor="#ffffff"
               android:layout_weight="1" />

            <CheckBox
         android:id="@+id/staysignedin"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight=".1" 
         android:text="@string/staysignedin" />


     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="10"
         android:text="Stay signed in" />

       </LinearLayout>
```

---

**Full Solution** -----------------------------------

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/signin_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:background="@layout/bordersignin"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/signin"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_weight=".2" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/staysignedinCheck"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:text="@string/staysignedin" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/staysignedinText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/staysignedinCheck"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                android:text="Stay signed in" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

---

**Result for Sign in button, checkbox , and "stay signed in" textview**

[image: result]

Comment: Remove `android:layout_gravity="left|center"` from TextView's attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You have some options here:

1. Change the width of your LinearLayout to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`. But this will not fill the whole width. I don't know if this is your desired setup.
2. For all three Views use this: `android:layout_weight="1"`. Then every View will have the same room. How codeMagic said, you should set the height / width to 0dp for horizontal / vertical orientation of your LinearLayout to prevent the View to be drawn twice.

Comment: If you're going to mention `weights` don't forget that `width` of each child should be `0dp` for `horizontal` orienation and `height="0dp"` for `vertical` orientation

Answer (score 0):

Your `CheckBox` seems innocent to me. The problem is here:

```
android:layout_gravity="left|center"
```

Using `layout_gravity`, you are telling the parent how to position the TextView within itself.

To position the text within the TextView(example): If you had a TextView filling up the entire screen width, and you needed to center the text within the TextView, you would use `android:gravity="center"`. This would center the text *within* the TextView.

To solve the problem, replace your TextView's setup with :

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Stay signed in" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be help to you..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signin_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Signing"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/staysignedin"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="StaySignedin" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Stay signed in" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/signin_button"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:padding="5dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
           android:background="@layout/bordersignin"
           android:textColor="#ffffff"
           android:text="@string/signin" />

       <CheckBox
           android:id="@+id/staysignedin"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/staysignedin" />

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="Stay signed in" />
   </LinearLayout>
```